# GBM: Predict the response variable measured in {0,20}

Tags: r, feature-selection, boosting

I need to predict the response that has values in {0,20}. Should it be used as a factor or as a numeric value? How does it influence on the prediction error?

I am using GBM with the Gaussian distribution to predict this variable, and the accuracy is very low.

```
gbm_model <- gbm(target~., data=traindf, distribution = "gaussian", n.trees = 500, 
                 bag.fraction = 0.75, cv.folds = 5, interaction.depth = 3)
```

For predicting I am using this code:

```
response_column <- which(colnames(testdf) == "target")
predictions_gbm <- predict(gbm_model, newdata = testdf[, -response_colum], 
                           n.trees = 500, type = "response")
```

Comment: To be clear, the notation {0, 20} means a set with just two elements, 0 and 20. Is that what you mean? Or do you mean [0, 20], the set of all real numbers *x* with 0 ≤ *x* ≤ 20? Or do you mean the integers 0 through 20?

Comment: @Kodiologist: I mean the integers 0 through 20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classifying cases into 21 different classes is hard, so when your response variable is an integer in 0 … 20, you probably don't want to just convert it to a factor. It's hard to give more concrete advice than that without knowing much about the distribution of the data or where the data comes from or what the data is about. You can try transformations of the response variable (such as adding 1 and taking the logarithm) or cutting it into a few discrete categories (like 0 through 10 and 11 through 20). Decisions about how to code the response variable should be made with reference to its meaning (is 11 a sensible threshold?), its distribution (try not to create categories with only a few training samples), and your model.

In any case, remember that you can clip your predictions to [0, 20]; there's no sense in predicting something outside the range of the response variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide your response variable 20 and use a logistic function and then multiply by 20 afterward.